# Implicit style showing up in designer but not when app is running

Tags: wpf, styles, scrollbar, resourcedictionary

I have styled a scrollbar (which uses TargetType as scrollbar rather than x:Key to assign the style) in   a ResourceDictionary in a Resource project called *ControlResources.*

The style:

```
DefaultScrollBarStyle.xaml (ResourceDictionary):

 <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{StaticResource Foreground}" 
                          Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundHighlighted}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushHighlighted}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushSelected}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButtonBackgroundHighlighted}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundHighlighted}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushHighlighted}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushSelected}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"/>
        <Track Name="PART_Track"
            Grid.Row="1"
            IsDirectionReversed="true">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"/>
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Content="M 0 4 L 4 8 L 4 0 Z" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"/>
        <Track Name="PART_Track"
            Grid.Column="1"
            IsDirectionReversed="false">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"/>
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Content="M 4 4 L 0 8 L 0 0 Z" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}"  >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The Library manifest it is located in within *ControlResources* looks like....

```
ResourceLibrary.xaml (another ResourceDictionary):

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!--BaseControlStyles-->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseControlStyles/DefaultTabControlStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseControlStyles/DefaultExpanderStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseControlStyles/DefaultScrollBarStyle.xaml"/>
    <!--Brushes-->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes/DefaultColorTheme.xaml"/>
    .
    .
    .
```

Which is routed to MyProject (main project) through Appl.xaml...

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ControlResources;component/ResourceDictionaries/ResourceLibrary.xaml"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

So how is it that I can see it in the designer but not when my project is running? There are no errors and I've rebuilt my solution several times.  (Note: the usual bug fix for this issue is included by `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"/>` but even that isn't helping.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using Snoop or wpfexplorer to see whether the style is actually applied?

Comment: I'm only a little bit familiar with Snoop. How will it allow me to see  if a style is applied? Even if it is being applied, I am not so sure knowing that will help. I think this has to do with generic.xaml "theme-ing" and that ScrollBars look for styles before resorting to an implicit style (one with a TargetType and not x:Key).

Comment: Snoop lets you check what's been applied by walking the visual tree (or pressing ctrl-shift over a visual element) and then checking to see if its Style has been set. Knowing this helps you by narrowing whether you have a problem applying the style, or if the style isn't changing the controls look properly. Although you can also identify this by adding a key, and directly applying it to the control.